# Plot Scipy Sparse Matrix Generated from Sklearn in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I've written code to cluster 60 documents using `sklearn`'s Kmeans algorithm:

Selection 1: Obtain `token_dict` (probably not that important):

```
for hashtag in hashtags:
    ob = users_tweeting(hashtag, 20)
    tweets = ob[1]
    overall = ""
    for tweet in tweets:
        tweet = tweet.lstrip()
        tweet = tweet.rstrip()
        # processing here
        overall += " "
        overall += tweet

    lower = overall.lower()
    nopunct = punctuation_marks.sub("", lower)        
    token_dict[hashtag] = nopunct
```

Selection 2: Vectorize and cluster the documents

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize, ngram_range = (1, 5))
tfs = tfidf.fit_transform(token_dict.values())
X = tfs

print("n_samples: %d, n_features: %d" % X.shape)

km = KMeans(n_clusters=3, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=10, tol = 1e-8, verbose=True)

print("Clustering sparse data with %s" % km)
t0 = time()
km.fit(X)
print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))

labels = km.labels_
centroids = km.cluster_centers_
figure = pl.figure(1)
ax = Axes3D(figure)
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2])
pl.show()
```

X is a Scipy sparse matrix that looks like

```
(0, 4558)     0.076421768112
(0, 5427)     0.015537938012
(0, 12380)    0.00517931267068
(0, 12554)    0.00517931267068
(0, 522)      0.116643751329
(0, 14100)    0.0120665949651
(0, 6851)     0.0723995697903
(0, 13100)    0.144799139581
(0, 14642)    0.0241331899
...
```

The error obtained is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "features.py", line 185, in <module>
    ob = keywords(['#happy', '#sad', '#feelingsick'])
  File "features.py", line 106, in keywords
    ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], X[:, 2])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 2180, in scatter
    patches = Axes.scatter(self, xs, ys, s=s, c=c, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 6337, in scatter
    self.add_collection(collection)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1481, in add_collection
    self.update_datalim(collection.get_datalim(self.transData))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/collections.py", line 185, in get_datalim
    offsets = np.asanyarray(offsets, np.float_)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 512, in asanyarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

It's pretty much the same error mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19980460/sklearn-gmm-raises-valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-on-sp), but I'm not sure how to resolve it. The goal is to plot the clusters (not just the centroids).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `X.todense()` turns the sparse matrix in to a regular dense one.  `X.A` (or `toarray()` produces a regular numpy array.